# How to use CASE or IF-statement in Postgres to select from different table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I want to make a selection from one of many tables. This selection depends on some condition. How can I make it?
I suppose it should be some like this (but it doesn't work):

```
CASE x
    WHEN x=1 THEN
       select Id,Name from table1
    WHEN x=2 THEN
       select Id,Name from table2
    WHEN x=3 THEN
       select Id,Name from table3
END CASE;
```

Comment: Where does `x` come from?

Comment: It should be as parameter for TFDQuery from delphi (or it is also can be as in-parameter stored procedure in database)

Comment: Why can't you do the `IF` in Delphi? And why do you have three different tables storing the same information? From the example you have given, a single table with an additional column `x` would be better

Comment: It's a bad practice - dynamic creation of SQL in runtime. Different tables has different information. Only 2 fields are common - Id and Name

Comment: Not sure I agree on IF statements being bad in code for SELECT statements, the logic has to go somewhere, SQL or Code, it's better placed where you can see it for most cases

Comment: You can't put sub-queries in a SQL CASE statement, to avoid that you would either put an IF statement in SQL (which is best done in a stored procedure/function) or through a UNION where the first column is a key, will post as answer

Comment: Why would there be any dynamic SQL? You just run three different (static) SQL statements depending on a variable inside Delphi. And besides: dynamic SQL (if done correctly) is **not** "bad practice"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inefficient solution the queries all 3 tables, but immitates a switch statement in code (assuming the retrieved columns are equivalent)

```
declare @inputValue int = 1

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 1 [key], Id from table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, Id from table2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, Id from table3
) x
where x.[key] = @inputValue
```

Comment: That is invalid syntax for Postgres

Comment: I mocked it up using SQL Server thinking it was ANSI T-SQL, I now understand that you can't declare inline variables in postgres, thank you

Comment: Thank you! Correct way is: SELECT 1 as key, Id from table1

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM table1
WHERE x = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT id, name
FROM table2
WHERE x = 2
UNION ALL
SELECT id, name
FROM table3
WHERE x = 3
```

Only one table's data will be returned (if `x` is any of those values).